# Problemas com o resultado de uma soma entre números do tipo double

Tags: java, double

Quero fazer o seguinte calculo:

**615.6555 + 566**

Esperava este resultado:

**1181.6555**

Porem, esta me retornando este:

**1181.6554999999998**

Como resolvo este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cálculos matemáticos sempre use o BigDecimal. BigDecimal é uma classe que trabalha com números de ponto flutuante de precisão arbitrária, a qual te escolher quanto de precisão você quer usar. Mas há uma pegadinha interessante aqui, caso você use BigDecimal dessa forma:

```
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(615.6555);
BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(566);

System.out.println(b1.add(b2));
```

Você vai receber o mesmo resultado inesperado. A própria documentação prevê essa possibilidade: ["Os resultados deste construtor podem ser imprevisíveis"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-). Você tem duas soluções para lidar esse problema, de acordo com a própria documentação, a primeira seria usar String:

```
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(615.6555));
```

E a segunda, caso você queira manter o double ao invés de convertê-lo, use o método estático valueOf:

```
BigDecimal b1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(615.6555);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para contas com grande quantidade de casas decimais pode ser interessante utilizar a classe

```
java.math.BigDecimal
```

Sendo assim, a conta ficaria dessa forma:

```
BigDecimal valor1 = new BigDecimal("615.6555");
BigDecimal valor2 = new BigDecimal("566");
BigDecimal soma = valor1.add(valor2);
System.out.println(soma); // Imprime 1181.6555
```

Além disso, com essa classe você consegue controlar de maneira fácil a precisão dos valores da dízima com o método **setScale**, e claro, além de outras operações aritméticas. Veja um exemplo prático e didático:

[Java.math.BigDecimal.setScale() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/bigdecimal_setscale_rm_roundingmode.htm)